# How to convert LocalDateTime object into ISO string including time zone?

Tags: kotlin, datetime-format, threetenbp

I am trying to convert a date/time string back and forth into a `LocalDateTime` object. I am using [*ThreeTenBp*](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) as the date/time library.

#### String -> LocalDateTime

```
val actual = LocalDateTime.parse("2016-12-27T08:15:05.674+01:00", 
                                 DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME)
val expected = LocalDateTime.of(2016, 12, 27, 8, 15, 5, 674000000)
assertThat(actual).isEqualTo(expected) // Successful
```

#### LocalDateTime -> String

```
val dateTime = LocalDateTime.of(2016, 12, 27, 8, 15, 5, 674000000)
val actual  = dateTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME)
assertThat(actual).isEqualTo("2016-12-27T08:15:05.674+01:00") // Fails
```

For some reason the time zone is missing:

> expected: <...6-12-27T08:15:05.674[+01:00]"> but was:<...6-12-27T08:15:05.674[]">
>   Expected :"2016-12-27T08:15:05.674+01:00"
>   Actual   :"2016-12-27T08:15:05.674"

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`LocalDateTime` is offset/timezone agnostic class. You need an `OffsetDateTime` class.

String -> OffsetDateTime

```
val actual = OffsetDateTime.parse("2016-12-27T08:15:05.674+01:00", DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME)
val expected = OffsetDateTime.of(2016, 12, 27, 8, 15, 5, 674000000, ZoneOffset.of("+01:00"))
assertThat(actual).isEqualTo(expected)
```

OffsetDateTime -> String

```
val dateTime = OffsetDateTime.of(2016, 12, 27, 8, 15, 5, 674000000, ZoneOffset.of("+01:00"))
val actual  = dateTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME)
assertThat(actual).isEqualTo("2016-12-27T08:15:05.674+01:00")
```

Comment: Can we use Annotation to deserialise?
i.e

@SomeDeserializeAnnotation

LocalDateTime incomingIso8601DateTime;
?