# How to convert format date from iso in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

i'm still a beginner in android and kotlin.

I have a date `2020-04-05T22:38:16.295985+07:00`

and expected value is `05 April 2020 22:38:16`

How do that in kotlin ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert LocalDateTime object into ISO string including time zone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41656756/how-to-convert-localdatetime-object-into-iso-string-including-time-zone)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting ISO 8601-compliant String to java.util.Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201925/converting-iso-8601-compliant-string-to-java-util-date) (not that you should want to convert to `java.util.Date`, that class is poorly designed and long outdated; but some of the answers offer other and better solutions).

Answer (score 3):

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41656999/2754562)

```
val actual = OffsetDateTime.parse("2020-04-05T22:38:16.295985+07:00", DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME)
val formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm:ss")
val formatDateTime = actual.format(formatter)

println(formatDateTime) //05 April 2020 22:38:16
```